# Adding image to wp nav menu,along with menu link text

Tags: wordpress, menu, wp-nav-walker

How to add image to wp-nav menu,I want to display image and link text side by side.Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

If the images are icons then you could use an icon font set. There's [a plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/font-awesome-4-menus/) That makes this super easy.

Alternatively you could code this solution yourself by adding an icon font and using, Here's [a post about that](https://wptavern.com/how-to-add-font-awesome-icons-to-wordpress-menus).

Both of the above examples are using the Font Awesome icon font but there are [many others available](https://speckyboy.com/more-free-icon-fonts/).